# react-app-rewired build throws attempted import error

Tags: react-navigation, react-native-web

I have react project. When I use `craco build`, I get the following error:

```
    node_modules/@react-navigation/core/lib/module/getStateFromPath.js
    Attempted import error: 'parse' is not exported from 'query-string' (imported as 'queryString').
```

So clearly something is messed up with the import/exports, but "start" works correctly, and everything's fine with that. This only occurs on "build". I use `@craco/craco` instead of `react-scripts`.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you find a solution by any chance ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when using react-app-rewired.

You can try using craco to override your webpack config instead. Switching to craco somehow eliminates this error for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was already using `@craco/craco`, but the `@react-navigation/native` was in a nested `node_modules` folder.

```js
├── node-modules
├── src
     ├── node_modules
     ├── package.json // @react-navigation/native was here
├── package.json
```

I moved the dependecy upward to the root `package.json`

```js
├── node-modules
├── src
     ├── node_modules
     ├── package.json
├── package.json // @react-navigation/native is here now
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly something is messed up with the import/exports, but "start" works correctly, and everything's fine with that. This only occurs on "build". I use "customize-cra" to get rid of the ModuleScopePlugin so I can import outside of src.

```
const { removeModuleScopePlugin, override, babelInclude, addBabelPlugins } = 
require("customize-cra");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = override(
 removeModuleScopePlugin(),        // (1)
  babelInclude([
   path.resolve("src"),
   path.resolve("../components/src"),  // (2)
   path.resolve('../../node_modules'),
 ]),
addBabelPlugins([require.resolve('babel-plugin-react-native-web')])
);
```

This is my config-overrides.js. My tsconfig was not changed, it's the same that ships with cra. If any additional information is needed, I'll add that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation, which I solved. I'll start by explaining the problem that I encountered so my solution makes sense in context.

The `create-react-app` webpack config [only compiles standard ES features](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/v5.0.1/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js#L467) for files that [do not reside](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/v5.0.1/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js#L418) in the `app/src` directory, so I added `react-app-rewired` to my CRA package to enable local cross-package dependencies in a yarn workspace by adding the following `config-override.js`:

```
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  // Rewrite `babelLoader.include` to the parent directory to
  // support local cross-package dependencies.
  config.module.rules[1].oneOf[3].include = "/my/root";
  return config;
};
```

However, this caused the babel loader to run against scripts in `node_modules` that also matched the associated test pattern [`/\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/v5.0.1/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js#L417).

I fixed this by introducing an `exclude` pattern: `exclude: /.*\/node_modules\/.*/` to the loader.

The easiest way to make these changes would be to eject and edit `config/webpack.config.js` directly, but if you need to avoid ejecting, it's more lightweight to use [`patch-package`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) than `react-app-rewired`.